# System.requestVersion() does not work in Second Generation Packaging

Tags: apex, second-generation-packaging

## Environment

- `sfdx-cli/7.58.2 win32-x64 node-v12.16.3`
- API 48

## What's going on?

When trying to create a **managed** packaged version with Second Generation Packaging (2GP) -with code check- that contains this class:

```java
global with sharing class VersionClass {
    global static void controlMethod() {
        String foo = 'someString';
    }

    global static void versionMethod() {
        Version packageVersion = System.requestVersion();
    }
}
```

the following error occur when calling the method containing `System.requestVersion();` <sup>1</sup>

```
(1) Apex Test Failure: Class.foobarbaz.VersionClass.versionMethod: line 8, column 1
  Class.foobarbaz.TestVersionClass.test_versionMethod: line 17, column 1 System.ProcedureException: Method is not supported from an unmanaged namespace
```

Such errors do not occur with the First Generation Packaging.

## What's the expected behavior?

We expect the managed package version to be created without any errors while using 2GP.

## How to reproduce?

1. Clone the [MRC Repo](https://github.com/louis-bompart/furry-couscous/)
2. Ensure that you're setup for 2GP
3. Try to create a version. You should get the aforementioned error.

## Notes

1: This occurs outside of Apex test calls as well. We originally found the issue by calling a similar method through a RemoteAction in a VisualForce Page. But let's keep it simple for the example sake.

Comment: Note, the error is not reproducable without the codecheck (`-c` flag). Edited OP accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After contacting Salesforce, I had confirmation that Version is, to this day, not supported in 2GP, which caused the issue described here.

Update Oct.2021: still not supported.

The "least worst" workaround I found so far would be to generate an ApexClass w/ a static field or CustomMetadata that would contain the version,  in a CI/CD.

Comment: What should one use instead?

Comment: @gburnett should have put that, my bad. I edited my answer to include the least worst workaround we had. The other is of course to keep on using 1GP :/.

Comment: If the patch version isn't important to you, you can get much the same by querying `SELECT MajorVersion, MinorVersion FROM Publisher WHERE NamespacePrefix = 'yourNamespace'`. This also functions on a scratch org (albeit returning 0, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of using `System.requestVersion()` it is possible to create some custom logic to store the value of Version in PostInstallContext into some protected custom setting.

Then, when needed, the current package version can be read from that custom setting.

Another option would be to maintain the package version as a constant in some apex class and update that line with CI on every package version creation step.

Also, if you have access to Session Id and Tooling API, it is possible to perform Tooling Api query

```
SELECT Id, SubscriberPackageId, SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix,
    SubscriberPackage.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.Id,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.MajorVersion,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.MinorVersion,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.PatchVersion,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.BuildNumber 
FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage 
ORDER BY SubscriberPackageId
```