# How to engage subscribers to upgrade up to the most recent package version?

Tags: 2gp

We have new versions of a 2G Managed Package being released on a regular basis. There is an obvious way to notify the subscribers about new version release through the e-mailing or release notes on the public website. However, it doesn't seem to be effective enough.

What we are thinking about is to make some kind of proactive in-app notifications. You can think of it as a popup which will appear to user whenever they lands on the homepage of the app right in Salesforce. The main complexity is to make every single org which has the package installed aware about new version release whenever that happens. Displaying the notification itself is not a challenge at all.

Has anyone thought or implemented something similar? Could you please share your thoughts or the details of how the goal of engaging subscribers to upgrade up to the most recent app version can be achieved?

Comment: Why push upgrade is not an option(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/push_upgrade_intro.htm)?

Comment: It is an option, but it doesn't always work. Because of no explicit consent given, it might become a legal issue in case of some unintended impact for the customer org. Apart from that, new package version upgrade often requires some manual post upgrade steps to be done by subscriber which ca not be automated via InstallHandler, so the upgrade should be handled by user manually.

Comment: I have to say, the points you raise here are why we do not use push notifications either. IMHO what you need to do is add a "phone home" mechanism that your package uses (via a "remote site" definition) to connect to your PBO. Your PBO can expose a simple REST API used by this mechanism to return the latest product version. The package can call this periodically, check to see if the latest version is different to what is in the [Publisher](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150526/get-currently-installed-package-version-from-apex-class/378993#378993) table. If different, notify.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW! This is what I thought either. In order to avoid the necessity to authorize the request from the subscriber org, it might make more sense to expose some public API instead.